# get result from multithread for the same method

Tags: multithreading

I would like to parallelize my program to be fast, so my program is like that:

```
  Sim1 sim1 = new Sim1();
    for(Entry<Integer, HashSet<String>> entry : map_topics_words.entrySet()) {              
                Integer k = entry.getKey();
                Double sim = sim1.prob(word_m, entry.getValue());           
                sim_avg.put(k, sim);
                score += sim;           
}
```

and prob in the method in class Sim1 like that

```
public double prob(String w_i, HashSet<String> set_i){  
    Similarity sim = new Similarity();
    double score = 1;
    Iterator<String> it = set_i.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        score += sim.computeSim(w_i, it.next());            
    }
    score = score/set_i.size(); 
    return score;
}
```

and computeSim in the method in classe Similarity like that :

```
public double computeSim(String w_1, String w_2){   
return  cmp(w_1,w_2);
}
```

So I would like to use thread for the first method and thread for the second method, I tried different ways but I failed
Any help, please
Thank you

Comment: user, what was the language? What is the OS? Which ways did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the first method code as below. We can try this by using Executor framework by submitting the work of prob() method as [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) task so that It can be executed in different thread, and then by using [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) we can get the result for that particular call, for this we need to maintain one more map of key and corresponding `Future` object, Please see below code to understand it better, hope it may help you.

```
        Sim1 sim1 = new Sim1();
        Map<Integer, Future<Double>> workerMap = new HashMap<>();
        ExecutorService exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<String>> entry : map_topics_words.entrySet()) {
            Integer k = entry.getKey();
            workerMap.put(k, exe.submit(()->{    //Java 8 lamda
                return sim1.prob(word_m, entry.getValue());
            }));
        }

    //This loop is to get the result of prob() method for all the keys and process them further

       for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<String>> entry : map_topics_words.entrySet()) {
            Integer k = entry.getKey();
            try {
                Double sim = workerMap.get(k).get();
                sim_avg.put(k, sim);
                score += sim;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I will suggest you to google the working of Callable and Future in java, You can see this [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/threadpoolexecutor-callable-future-example/) also.